# SQL 2 tables, ios

Tags: ios, sql, database

I am making chat app and I want to story history in sql, I want that in messages VC I will see all users with whom I have chat, I want to have a history for every user. Do I need to have 2 sql tables here or how can I implement it?

I can make one sqlite table, but how to add another?

Comment: Use CoreData or MagicRecords, sql is only one per app

Comment: @shtefane you can have multiple SQLite files per app no problem. But this looks like great job for CoreData.

Comment: @shtefane Seriously? In a single app you can have any number of databases each with any number of tables. BTW - `sql` is actually being used out of context. `sql` is a language - `structured query language`. So perhaps you meant `sqlite` which is a specific database implementation. And FYI - CoreData uses `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can have multiple tables in your SQLite database, the answer is simply, yes, you can. Just issue the appropriate `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table you need.

If you're asking whether you can dynamically create additional tables at runtime (e.g. one for each chat session), yes, you could do that as well (again, just issue `CREATE TABLE` statements), but you probably don't want to do that. You generally want a fixed schema that is represented by a series of tables that captures your data model.

For example, if I was implementing a chat system with multiple users, I might implement three tables, a list of chat sessions, a list of which users engaged in each chat (on the assumption that you might have multiple users in a chat), and the individual chat messages in each session. I'd create these tables up-front, something like:

```sql
-- a list of chat sessions

create table session (session_id integer primary key autoincrement,
                      session_start_timestamp double);

-- a list of which users participated in the specified session

create table session_user(session_user_id integer primary key autoincrement,
                          session_user text not null,        -- who
                          session_id integer not null);      -- which session

-- the individual chat messages

create table chat_history (chat_id integer primary key autoincrement,
                           session_id integer not null,      -- which session
                           chat_timestamp real not null,     -- when
                           session_user_id integer not null, -- who
                           chat_message text);               -- what
```

Comment: By the way, it goes without saying that if you're going to do SQLite programming, save yourself a lot of heartaches and use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).